# How to force embedded python to use the same sys.path as command line one?

Tags: python, c++

I use `python` as embedded scripting language in Ubuntu 16 C++ application. I use `pip` to install additional modules (`mysql`, `regex`, etc). These modules work nice in command line python. However, embedded python can not load them. The reason is that `sys.path` of embedded python differs from command line one. Command line python `sys.path` follows:

```
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

Here `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` is path where `pip` installs modules.

Embedded python `sys.path` follows:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
```

Of course, it is possible to hardcode `pip` directory in C++ application and call `PySys_SetPath` with hardcoded arguments. However, this way looks badly for me; this will make application not portable (I compile the same code for Ubuntu, CentOS and Windows).

Command line python somehow "knows" where `pip` stores modules. So, there are any configuration file that contains these additional pathes. I run `printenv`, but no environment variable contains `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` string. One way is to run diagnostics script via command line python and send its output to `PySys_SetPath`. However, **are there any official, documented way to get all pathes where python installation searches for modules by calling API and not by running external process**?

Comment: This is a combination of C++ and Python. Mostly C++, try adding that tag to your post and it should catch the eye of the right programmers. @Vitaliy

Comment: I'll turn this into a full answer once I try it out, but in [cocotb](https://github.com/cocotb/cocotb/blob/54652c04ca52dbeb3b7515f37a45ec515a99e31e/src/cocotb/share/lib/embed/gpi_embed.cpp#L71-L108) we've been setting the program name to the path of the python executable, which causes `sys.path` to be loaded as it would if python were called as a script.

Answer (score 0):

If data, scripts, and or executable(s) are included in a package, they're installed in  (their default) separate directories rather than with the Python files.

This command should work just fine but fails to include the other files of a package (if it has any). To include any data, scripts, or executable(s) utilize `--prefix`, `--install-data`, and `--install-scripts` also known as [alternate installation](https://docs.python.org/3/install/index.html#alternate-installation).

```
pip install --install-option="--install-purelib=/foobar/packages" package_name
```

To permanently change the path, edit the `~/.pip/pip.conf` file to include:

```
[install]
install-option=--install-purelib=/foobar/packages
```

I highly recommend [`pip wheel`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/). It provides more control over package installment with areas such as: setup requirements, building, installation order, etc; documentation points of interests: [examples](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#examples), [controlling `setup_requires`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#controlling-setup-requires), and [using environment variables](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#using-environment-variables) which is probably the easiest.

One thing to note with `pip wheel` is:

> You have to use the **POSIX format** for variable names including brackets
>   around the uppercase name as shown in this example: ${API_TOKEN}. pip
>   will attempt to find the corresponding environment variable defined on
>   the host system at runtime.

Comment: So, what is the answer for the question: "are there any official, documented way to get all pathes where python installation searches for modules by calling API and not by running external process"?

Comment: As much as I researched into different official ways of changing installation path, I did not find anything that fit that exact description. I'm sorry for not directly answering that in my post. I did my best to give alternatives and examples. @Vitaliy